# SMPlayer not playing any sound

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, smplayer

I am trying to play various formats on SMPlayer but none of them have sound, mp4, mp3, flash videos after download from youtube, wav.

These are all playing with GNOME MPlayer, but I require the SMTube tool to watch youtube videos directly on SMPlayer. Sound is enabled. Here it is a [screenshot](http://imm.io/NYCX).

Comment: I had the same problem a while back. 2 things to consider: check in sound settings if the audio source is selected and install pavucontrol. For me THE tool for checking audio related problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rinzwind suggested, I went to the preferences (Ctrl+P), audio tab and changed the output controller from 'pulse' to 'alsa'. Now the sound is back, problem solved.